# hibernate update one to many items set

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, annotations

- Sales Order Entity.

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "sales_orders")
  @IdClass(ReceiptPK.class)
  public class SalesOrders implements Serializable {

      public SalesOrders() {
      }
      @Id
      protected Integer receiptID;
      @Id
      protected Integer dateKey;

      public SalesOrders(Integer receiptID, Integer dateKey) {
          this.receiptID = receiptID;
          this.dateKey = dateKey;
      }
  //order contains many details
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "salesOrders")
  @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
  private Set<SalesOrderDetails> orderDetails = new HashSet<SalesOrderDetails>();

  public Set<SalesOrderDetails> getOrderDetails() {
      return orderDetails;
  }

  public void setOrderDetails(Set<SalesOrderDetails> orderDetails) {
      this.orderDetails = orderDetails;
  }
  // other property ..
  ```
- Order Details Entity.

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "sales_order_details")
  public class SalesOrderDetails implements Serializable {

      public SalesOrderDetails() {
      }
      private int id;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      public int getId() {
          return id;
      }

      public void setId(int id) {
          this.id = id;
      }

      // Order holder
      private SalesOrders salesOrders;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "order_num", referencedColumnName = "receiptID"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "date_key", referencedColumnName = "dateKey")})
      public SalesOrders getSalesOrders() {
          return salesOrders;
      }

      public void setSalesOrders(SalesOrders salesOrders) {
          this.salesOrders = salesOrders;
      }
       // other property ...
  ```

**My Question** : When i try to remove Order item that doesn't affect on  `sales_order_details` .

```
            SalesOrders saleOrder = (SalesOrders) getSession().get(SalesOrders.class ,new ReceiptPK(receiptID,dateKey));
            saleOrder.getOrderDetails().remove(someDetails);
            getSession().beginTransaction();
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(saleOrder);
            getSession().getTransaction().commit();
```

**But `someDetails` doesn't removed.**

-- Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to commit the same transaction.

```
getSession().getTransaction().begin();
getSession().saveOrUpdate(saleOrder);
getSession().getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer,But this solution didn't help, order item didn't removed yet...

Comment: what about putting `saleOrder.getOrderDetails().remove(someDetails);` between begin and commit transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

For bi-directional associations you should(must) always ensure that the associations are set correctly.

- Do not allow direct access to your collections.
- Provide add and remove methods for modification.

---

```
public Set<SalesOrderDetails> getOrderDetails() {
  //force to use add/remove to ensure consistent object model
  return Collections.unmodifiableSet(orderDetails);
}

public void addOrderDetails(SalesOrderDetails salesOrderDetails){
 orderDetails.add(salesOrderDetails);
 salesOrderDetails.setSalesOrders(this); //important
}

public void removeOrderDetails(SalesOrderDetails salesOrderDetails){
 orderDetails.remove(salesOrderDetails);
 salesOrderDetails.setSalesOrder(null); //important
}
```

Additionally, have you implemented equals() and hashCode() on your Entitites i.e. when you call salesOrder.getOrderDetails().remove(someDetails) is anything actually being removed from the collection?

Probably not if you have not implemented equals() and hashCode() on SalesOrderDetails.

Fianlly, you shout set the orphanRemoval flag on the OneToMany mapping to true:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Orphan_Removal_.28JPA_2.0.29

Comment: Thanks you for your good notes, But when i remove `order detail` from `Order` that set `order FK` on `Sales_order_details` to `null` **BUT** row still exists on table and didn't removed !!.

Comment: See Orphan Removal: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Orphan_Removal_.28JPA_2.0.29